# looping issue with Crashlytics logging?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

My Swift app is getting killed by iOS (0x8badf00d), and it looks like Crashlytics is the culprit. Here's a section of a crash report - I assume it's Crashlytics because of the CLS prefixes on the code.

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.rsginc.rmove exhausted CPU time allowance of 4.70 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Background | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.550 (user 7.550, system 0.000), 10% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 5.119, 7% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001fab7d948 write + 8
1   rMove                           0x00000001048e6814 CLSSDKFileLog + 336
2   rMove                           0x00000001048f2128 __CLSFileWriteWithRetries_block_invoke + 128
3   rMove                           0x00000001048f203c CLSFileLoopWithWriteBlock + 56
4   rMove                           0x00000001048f23ac CLSFileFDWriteUInt64 + 128
5   rMove                           0x00000001048f248c CLSFileFDWriteInt64 + 116
6   rMove                           0x00000001048e6804 CLSSDKFileLog + 320
7   rMove                           0x00000001048f2128 __CLSFileWriteWithRetries_block_invoke + 128
8   rMove                           0x00000001048f203c CLSFileLoopWithWriteBlock + 56
9   rMove                           0x00000001048f23ac CLSFileFDWriteUInt64 + 128
10  rMove                           0x00000001048f248c CLSFileFDWriteInt64 + 116
11  rMove                           0x00000001048e6804 CLSSDKFileLog + 320
12  rMove                           0x00000001048f2128 __CLSFileWriteWithRetries_block_invoke + 128
13  rMove                           0x00000001048f203c CLSFileLoopWithWriteBlock + 56
14  rMove                           0x00000001048f23ac CLSFileFDWriteUInt64 + 128
15  rMove                           0x00000001048f248c CLSFileFDWriteInt64 + 116
...
```

The 5 repeated lines in that trace are repeated 102 times - I truncated it for StackOverflow character limits and readability.

I haven't been able to find others getting this problem - is this a known bug, or is there something I could be doing wrong in my Crashlytics calls?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your app is starting over 20 seconds duration. 
Take a look to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/) and find a part with code 0x8badf00d.

> The exception code 0x8badf00d indicates that an application has been terminated by iOS because a watchdog timeout occurred. The application took too long to launch, terminate, or respond to system events. One common cause of this is doing synchronous networking on the main thread. Whatever operation is on Thread 0 needs to be moved to a background thread, or processed differently, so that it does not block the main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue looks to me like an infinite loop in the Crashlytics code - there's none of my code in the stack trace for thread 0, so this is more a Crashlytics question than an 0xbadf00d question.

Comment: It looks like the crashlytics try and retry to write some log file again and again. Does it possible that device haven’t enough free space on disk?

Comment: No dice - plenty of storage left.